# Is RAID 5 still a viable option?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas

Without writing to much:
Is RAID 5 still a viable option in systems > 10TB space. I can handle some hours or maybe 1,2 days of recreation/extending - but more than that would be a pita.

I want to build a *small* home NAS with some throwaway virtual machines for developing purposes. I want to be able to extend the available disk space anytime without too much hassle. And when a drive fails I want to be able to recreate the raid in a decent amount of time.

Since it's a private NAS it's not a big deal when the recreation takes some time - like some hours to days. But a week or more is something I really want to avoid.

I would prefer using a software raid.

Answer (score 4):

> Is RAID 5 still a viable option?

Yes, for some setups it is. Example: Take a home user who want to store lots of movies (so mostly reads) and who does not backup all that often, yes does not want to loose everything when a disk dies.  RAID10 and RAID6 would also work in that example but RAID 5 uses less drives and thus is cheaper, lower power and less noisy.

For most other configurations: No, avoid it.

> I want to build a small home NAS with some throwaway virtual machines for
>   developing purposes.

That probably means that you also will write a lot. Go for HW RAID with cache (to avoid the write gap) or go for RAID 10. Or anything but RAID 5. Or accept a long rebuild or restore time.

Note that RAID is not a replacement for backups, thus I assume that you do have backups and that wiping an array and rebuilding it might be acceptable. And potentially much faster than resilvering it with a new disk.

Also note that many RAID implementation have a setting which determines how fast they recover. Thos eusually vary from 'Long restore time but users can continue to access the files without significant delay' to 'spent all your time rebuilding.'

> I want to be able to extend the available disk space anytime without too
>   much hassle.

This depends on what you call 'hassle' and if you want to keep everything in one volume.  It might be useful to look at ZFS.

> And when a drive fails I want to be able to recreate the RAID in
>   a decent amount of time.

What is 'a decent amount if time' ?  For RAID 5 and multi terabyte disks this might well take a weekend to restore.  Possible less if you wipe the array, create a new array with the broken disk replaced and restore from backup.  (Which raises the speed of reading from backups, which might be slow if they are on a different network).

Comment: I guess my question was a bit vague, right? ;) Would it be possible to calculate an estimated time to recreate a failed drive?

Comment: Sorry, got a phone call mid-edit.....  Time depends on a lot of things, which includes the hardware used (Computer or HW RAID, and which HW RAID), the settings (% of time spent on restoring vs keeping the array accesible), and ofcourse the disks themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing edit, really appreciate that. Could you add one or two sentences why ZFS? I heard about it but I'm not very familiar with it. Well this is the awkward moment to admit I don't have backups. It would be very annoying when data would be lost - but less pain than paying twice for storage/power for the backups ;)

Comment: I mainly mentioned ZFS because it has RAID-Z, which sort of is RAID 5 but better. And for home users fewer disks often is a good thing. Ditto for most home users  expensive RAID cards (which also can fail) are a bad thing. Both of these make ZFS interesting (if complex to learn).

Comment: On the other hand, ZFS is practically the hardest filesystem in existence to extend space on. You cannot add, extend, or reshape an array in any way whatsoever, nor can you add disks peace-meal. Your only option is to extend by adding an entire new array.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, it is. We handle more than 150 physical servers and most of them (in exception of some high-rate read-write servers, which have RAID10) are RAID5. The recreation time will depend on how much capacity the disk has, but keep in mind that disk failures are (or should be) a very infrequent situation, so if your disk fails you won't have data loss or service failure unless another disk fails between the time the first fails and the new reconstructs, which is even more infrequent unless you got some other hardware that is making your disks fail.

One clarification: If one disk fails you won't have service loss. Between the time it fails and you replace it, the rest of disks will still work and everything will work as usual. The problem happens when more than one disk fails.

Comment: In our case for a 2TB drive the recreation time is about 12-15hrs. We use hardware right controllers, though.

Comment: So can we say that a 4tb drive would be aout 30hours ?

Comment: Depends on the RAID software/hardware used, but it should be proportional, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no, if you care about your data. Absolutely yes if you don't mind losing it.

Since you've already said you have no backups, there is a high a risk of additional bad sectors (= data loss) if you lose a drive.

Recreation time isn't the issue. Software RAID rebuild can easily saturate the STR of any modern HDD. A 10TB array of 6x2TB drives would rebuild in about 4 hours.

The issue is without background scrubs, you will almost certainly already have  at least one bad sector on one drive if any other drive fails. The effect of this can vary from your array going read-only to complete corruption of the entire filesystem.

Addendum: For typical development and testing VMs, you are far better not using a NAS at all. Though I fail to see how you can use up ~10TB with "throwaway VMs"

Comment: Woopsie. The vm's are additional to the actual NAS - thus I setup a *server* instead of going with some kind of qnap nas or w/e.

Comment: I would recommend ZFS with RAID-Z2.